# How does git-review work?

Tags: git, gerrit, githooks, git-review

I want to know, how exactly does `git review` command work? I mean does it use `git push` command (internally) or something else to upload the changes to gerrit. This information would be useful for me while writing git hooks for `git review`.

Comment: `git review -v` prints out all of the git commands that are being run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/git-review#What_happens_when_you_submit_a_change):

When you submit a change, `git review` does the following things:

- it looks up which branch to push to (production or whatever) in the `.gitreview` file. If it can't find this information, it pushes to `master`
- it figures out what "topic" to put on the revision (you can set the topic manually with `-t`)

  - if you're resubmitting a downloaded change, it will reuse the tag of the original change
  - if your commit summary contains a bug number like `bug 12345`, the tag will be `bug/12345`
  - otherwise, the tag will be the name of your local branch
- it rebases your change against the `HEAD` of the branch you're pushing to (use `-R` to skip this)
- if you are submitting more than one change at once, or submitting a change that's based on another unmerged change, it will ask you whether you really meant to do that (use `-y` to skip this)
- it pushes the change for review

Comment: What is the location of .gitreview file? And what to edit?

Comment: the location of .gitreview  file is the root of you tree. and you change  the following attribute.

[gerrit]
defaultbranch=<branch_name>